# How to extract the given keys in one dictionary from another into a new dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I'm trying to practice sets and dictionaries, and one thing I've been finding is myself stuck on this practice problem over and over.

For example if I have a dictionary like

```
employees =[
{
    "name": "Jamie Mitchell",
    "job": "Head Chef",
    "city": "Toronto",
},
{
    "name": "Michell Anderson",
    "job": "Line Cook",
    "city": "Mississauga",
  }
]
```

How would I extract the second part of the dictionary from the first in order to only have the information on the right be in a new dictionary?

Comment: `employees` is a list not a dictionary. Michelle's info (which *is* a dict) is just `employees[1]`.

Comment: `for key in employee.keys():`.  You can also write `for key in employee:`, since iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys.

Comment: what do you mean with the *second* part of that dictionary?, It`s about**keys**: ```[name, job city]``` or **values**:```[Jamie Mitchell, Head Chef, Toronto]```?

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick Answer:

`employees` is a list of dictionaries so you can just directly index the list to get Michell:

```
newDict = employees[1]
```

#### More Detailed Answer:

Firstly, here is how you create a key-value pair in a dictionary:

```
dct = {}
dct['color'] = 'blue' # dct = {'color':'blue'}
```

Knowing this, all you would need to copy a dictionary is the keys and values. You can use the `.keys()`,`.values()`, and `.items()` methods of dictionaries to do this.

```
dct.keys() # returns a list of all the keys -> ['color']
dct.values() # returns a list of all the values -> ['blue']
dct.items() # return a list of all the pairs as tuples -> [('color','blue')]
```

There are other options to copy as another user has mentioned however I strongly suggest you get used to work with the 3 methods listed above. If you haven't already, make sure you are really comfortable with lists before you jump into dictionaries and combined structures. You already seem to know how to work loops so hopefully this is helpful enough, good luck!

Comment: I'm trying to store the values in a new dictionary so I'm using                                   
new_dict={employees}
print(new_dict.values())
but it isn’t working. My question is how can I store the values using your .values() suggestion in a new dictionary?

Comment: Ok wait, so a dictionary must always have key-value pairs. If you want to copy just the values of a dictionary, then you use a list. I am slightly confused now about what exactly you are trying to get.

Comment: @lukan In your post, add a section that details how you want the dictionary to be before and after. So like 'this is the starting dictionary' and 'this is the result I want', and just type out how you want the dictionary. We can work from there

Answer (score 0):

You have them backwards; the outer one `[]` is a list. The inner ones `{}` are dictionaries.

You can get the second one with `employees[1]` (indexing starts from 0) or the last one with `employees[-1]` (in this case they are the same).

If you need a copy, you can call `.copy()` on the result:

```
second_employee = employees[1]
copied_details = second_employee.copy()
```